# Concatenation of two regexs

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have the following exported text file:

```
14:00:01 type1 "xyz" has no relationships... ಠ_ಠ
14:00:01 type2 "xyza" has no relationships... ಠ_ಠ
14:00:01 type2 "aaaa" has no relationships... ಠ_ಠ
14:00:01 type3 "asdg" has no relationships... ಠ_ಠ
14:00:01 type4 "dhj" has no relationships... ಠ_ಠ
```

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve two informations from this file

1. The type (in this case, the element after the time and before what is inside the double quote)
2. What is inside the double quote

**Output expected**:

> type1 xyz
>
> type2 xyza
>
> type2 aaaa
>
> type3 asdg
>
> type4 dhj

With my current code, I can get the content inside the double quote, but I don't know how to get the type and merge it with my regex:

```
import os, yaml
import argparse
import re
with open('stackoverflow.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    matches=re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"',str(content))#get the content within the double quote
for x in matches:
    print(x)
```

**Current output**:

> xyz
>
> xyza
>
> aaaa
>
> asdg
>
> dhj

Comment: Do I understand it right you only have one match per line? And it is always the first match on a line?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I could only get what is whithin the double quote

Comment: Yes, I see. So, my guess was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `(\w+) "([^"]*)"` (you can check [its demo here](https://regex101.com/r/zJFATq/1/)) to get a match on each line and then format the output as you need by grabbing the two groups from each match if found:

```py
import re
matches = []
rx = re.compile(r'(\w+) "([^"]*)"')
with open('stackoverflow.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = rx.search(line)
        if m:
            matches.append(f'{m.group(1)} {m.group(2)}')
```

See [the Python demo](https://ideone.com/8zQl7a):

```py
import re
file=r'''14:00:01 type1 "xyz" has no relationships... ಠ_ಠ
14:00:01 type2 "xyza" has no relationships... ಠ_ಠ
14:00:01 type2 "aaaa" has no relationships... ಠ_ಠ
14:00:01 type3 "asdg" has no relationships... ಠ_ಠ
14:00:01 type4 "dhj" has no relationships... ಠ_ಠ'''
matches = []
rx = re.compile(r'(\w+) "([^"]*)"')
for line in file.splitlines():
    m = rx.search(line)
    if m:
        matches.append(f'{m.group(1)} {m.group(2)}')
            
print(matches)
# => ['type1 xyz', 'type2 xyza', 'type2 aaaa', 'type3 asdg', 'type4 dhj']
```

Answer (score 2):

If your txt files will ALWAYS have that structure, I would simply do:

```
with open('stackoverflow.txt') as f:
    matches = [' '.join(line.split(' ')[1:3]) for line in f.readlines()]

for x in matches:
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
type1 "xyz"
type2 "xyza"
type2 "aaaa"
type3 "asdg"
type4 "dhj"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.findall`:

```
with open('stackoverflow.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    matches = re.findall(r'\b\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} (\S+) "(.*?)"', content)
    print(matches)
```

For the data you gave above, `matches` would contain:

```
[('type1', 'xyz'), ('type2', 'xyza'), ('type2', 'aaaa'), ('type3', 'asdg'), ('type4', 'dhj')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a second group to the regex:

```
import re
with open('stackoverflow.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    matches = re.findall(r' (\S+) "(.+?)"',content)
for x in matches:
    print(x[0], x[1])
```

Note: consider using `re.finditer` and iterating directly over f instead of `re.findall` and `f.readlines`, as they use iterators instead of lists.